# Why is integer output 0 when collecting string from input

Tags: c++, std, stdin, cin, stdstring

I'm new to C++ and am working through Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practices. In section 3.3, he gives the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
  std::string firstName;
  int age;
  std::cin >> firstName >> age;
  std::cout << "Hello, " << firstName << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

As per the text, I entered '22 Carlos' and expect the output to be 22 followed by some random number or 0. Fine, I get 0.

I then initialise the variables and input the same '22 Carlos':

```
string firstName = "???";
int age = -1;
```

I expect the output to be 'Hello, 22 (age -1)', as stated in the text, but instead get 'Hello, 22 (age 0)'. Why?

Comment: Because your STL's implementation of `operator>>` is explicitly setting invalid int input to 0. That is allowed,though the behavior was undefined prior to C++11, but is guaranteed in C++11 and later.

Comment: Just check how to recover from stream failed state due to invalid inputs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's not a duplicate question as linked. I'm asking why the disparity between the book and the actual output, the linked question is asking if anyone uses the extraction operator. Totally different.

Comment: Whoever closed this question as a duplicate didn't read the answers to the duplicate, because NONE of them answer this question. So I'm reopening this question.

Comment: You can always refer to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) before asking here, sorry.

Comment: @Remy Whoever wrote that question didn't bother to research.

Comment: It's wrong, string cannot receive input from cin. Use getline;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get `age` set to `0` is [because](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) (assuming you are on c++11 or higher):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
> expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set. (until C++11)
>
> **If extraction fails, zero is written to value** and failbit is set.
> (**since C++11**)

Just a side note, VC++ compiler was not following this standard until recently https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/285201/the-value-is-not-zeroed-after-failure-but-it-shoul.html